# Console: ReferenceError: stopPropagation is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events, datatables

What's the problem here? I get the search I want, but it doesn't redraw the table when using the exact match regex column. I'm using a single column to better filter a ranking value that is numeric.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready( function () {
    // Setup - add a text input to each header cell
    jQuery('#table1 thead tr#filterrow th').each( function () {
        var title = jQuery('#table1 thead th').eq( jQuery(this).index() ).text();
        jQuery(this).html( '<input type="text" onclick="stopPropagation(event);" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } ); 
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    jQuery('#table1 tfoot tr#filterrow th').each( function () {
        var title = jQuery('#table1 tfoot th').eq( jQuery(this).index() ).text();
        jQuery(this).html( '<input type="text" onclick="stopPropagation(event);" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );
    // DataTable
var table = jQuery('#table1').DataTable( {
    orderCellsTop: true,
                aLengthMenu: [[-1, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500],[ "All", 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500]],
                iDisplayLength: -1,
        dom: 'B<"lb">lfrtip',
                responsive: 'true',
        buttons: [
            { extend: 'copy',
                oSelectorOpts: {
                    filter: 'applied'
                }
            },
            { extend: 'csv',
                oSelectorOpts: {
                    filter: 'applied'
                }
            },
            { extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                oSelectorOpts: {
                    filter: 'applied'
                }
            },
            { extend: 'print',
                autoPrint: false,
                oSelectorOpts: {
                    filter: 'applied'
                }
            }
            ]
} );
    // Apply the filter
    jQuery("#table1 thead input").on( 'keyup change', function () {
        table
            .column( jQuery(this).parent().index()+':visible' )
            .search(this.value)
            .draw();
    } );
    jQuery("#table1 tfoot input").on( 'keyup change', function () {
        table
            .column( jQuery(this).parent().index()+':visible' )
            .search(this.value)
            .draw();
    } );
    jQuery("#table1 thead input").on( 'keyup change', function () {
        table
            .column(4)
            .search("^" + this.value + "$", true, false, true)
            .draw();
    } );
    jQuery("#table1 tfoot input").on( 'keyup change', function () {
        table
            .column(4)
            .search("^" + this.value + "$", true, false, true)
            .draw();
    } );
  function stopPropagation(evt) {
        if (evt.stopPropagation !== undefined) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            evt.cancelBubble = true;
        }
    }
} );
</script>
```

I feel like something in my code should be condensed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `stopPropagation()` method is defined inside `ready` event handler and is not visible outside of it.

Move definition `stopPropagation()` outside of `ready` event handler:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function () {
   // ... skipped ...  
});

function stopPropagation(evt) {
    if (evt.stopPropagation !== undefined) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        evt.cancelBubble = true;
    }
}
```

**NOTES**

- Since you're using jQuery you could rewrite the same with less code. And the `click` event handler could be placed inside `ready` event handler.
- You're assigning `keyup change` twice for each `input` element in footer and header. Consider rewriting your code as shown in [this example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html).

Comment: This takes care of the error, but I still have the issue with the draw of the table upon input into column 4. If I enter something, everything shows correctly, but if I backspace everything out to a blank value, nothing shows.

Comment: @dgodfather, added link to the [example](http://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html) where filtering is done properly.